# Passing a PDF to a UIActivityViewController

Tags: ios, swift, pdf, uikit

In the app I'm playing with, I can already build and view a PDF programmatically. The part I'm having trouble with is I want the user to be able to "share" it using whichever apps can support the file (i.e. email, dropbox, etc...).

Here is where I am with the code:

```
@IBAction func actionShare(_ sender: Any) {
    let activityViewController: UIActivityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [pdfPath = createPDF()], applicationActivities: nil)
    activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView=self.view
    present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

createPDF() is a function that creates the PDF and returns the document path as a string.

When I hit the 'Share' button, all I get is this:

[image]

The compiler doesn't yell at me, and only has this to say:

```
[MC] Filtering mail sheet accounts for bundle ID: Business-Account-Finder, source account management: 1
[MC] Result: YES
[MC] Filtering mail sheet accounts for bundle ID: Business-Account-Finder, source account management: 1
[MC] Result: YES
```

On the test iPad I am using, it has mail configured with a functioning Gmail account. It has no non-default apps installed and nothing but the email account settings have been personalized.

Any ideas on what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things:

1. You need a `URL`, not a file path as a string.
2. Don't use `[pdfPath = createPDF()]`.

Here's some updated code:

```
@IBAction func actionShare(_ sender: Any) {
    let pdfPath = createPDF()
    let pdfURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: pdfPath)
    let activityViewController: UIActivityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [pdfURL], applicationActivities: nil)
    activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView=self.view
    present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

You should also set `sourceRect` whenever you use `sourceView` on a `popoverPresentationController`.

You also need to set the `completionWithItemsHandler` so you know when it's done.

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thanks for the updated code and the tips. =D